# Error accessing MQs from .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, ibm-mq

I have a VB.NET console application that must write a message onto a queue (resides on the mainframe). We have all the clustering and everything set-up by our admin. We already have an existing windows service that successfully listens to messages and also writes messages to various queues.

I have basically re-used most of my code from the windows service project.

But when I try to access the queue manager, I hit the exception "MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE". The error log from the Websphere MQ folder says

```
AMQ9213: A communications error for  occurred.
EXPLANATION:
An unexpected error occurred in communications.
ACTION:
The return code from the  call was 0 (X'0'). Record these values and tell the systems administrator.
```

Here is the complete exception stack.

```
IBM.WMQ.MQException was unhandled
Message="MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE"
Source="amqmdnet"
StackTrace:
   at IBM.WMQ.MQBase.throwNewMQException()
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName)
   at LPMQtoClarify.Module1.Main() in D:\LPDEV\Developers\X173036_Santhanam\LPMQtoClarify\LPMQtoClarify\Module2.vb:line 47
   at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Here's part of my code. The exception occurs in the following line

```
QueueManager = New MQQueueManager(TransParmRec.MQManager)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Dim pos As Integer = 3
Dim clarifyReturnCode As Integer = 0
Dim clarifyRequestMessage As String = String.Empty

Dim QueueManager As MQQueueManager
clarifyQLauncherName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.[Get]("MQ_CLARIFY_REQUEST_Q")


Dim initRetCode As Integer = 0
Dim errorMessage As String = ""
initRetCode = GetTransInfo(TransParmRec, dbConnectionString, errorMessage)


MQEnvironment.Hostname = TransParmRec.MQHostName
MQEnvironment.Channel = TransParmRec.MQChannel

If TransParmRec.PortNumber.ToString().Length > 0 Then
    MQEnvironment.Port = Convert.ToInt32(TransParmRec.PortNumber)
End If
If TransParmRec.SecExit.ToString().Length > 0 Then
    MQEnvironment.SecurityExit = TransParmRec.SecExit
End If


QueueManager = New MQQueueManager(TransParmRec.MQManager)
Using sw As New StreamWriter("C:\FCLARIFYMQ.REQ", True)
    If QueueManager Is Nothing Then
        sw.WriteLine("Queue Manager is null")
    Else
        sw.WriteLine("Queue Manager is not null")

    End If
End Using
```

Comment: `Record these values and tell the systems administrator`

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your host name or port number. MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE is returned if host name or port number is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The code worked when I ran the application under a different user account. The MQ privileges are set-up for a different user account which is not the same as the admin account.